# Mensaje de aviso en PHP al no encontrar registros

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buen día, tengo una página que me busca registros en una tabla que tengo en mysql, la pregunta es.. **¿¿si no me encuentra ningún registro que código he de poner y donde para que me salga un aviso como "No se ha encontrado ningun registro" ??**

Adjunto el cógido que realiza la búsqueda a mysql (busq.php)

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 $dia=$_POST['dia'];
 $mes=$_POST['mes'];
 $año=$_POST['año'];

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $con->real_query("SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE dia like '%$dia%' and mes 
 LIKE '%$mes%' and anio like '%$año%'");
 $resultado= $con->use_result();

 while($muestra=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
 echo'<tr>';
 echo'<td>'.$muestra['dia'].'</td>';
 echo'<td>'.$muestra['mes'].'</td>';
 echo'<td>'.$muestra['anio'].'</td>'; 
 echo'</tr>';
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Y este es el código donde se encuentra el formulario de búsqueda:

```
 <title>busqueda</title>
 <p>
 <form name="form1" method="POST" action="busqueda.php" id="resultado" 
 onKeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) event.returnValue = false;">
 <h2>Buscar Usuario</h2>
 <input name="dia" type="text" id="busqueda" placeholder="Ingrese el día">
 <input name="mes" type="text" id="mesqueda" placeholder="Ingrese el mes">
 <input name="año" type="text" id="añoqueda" placeholder="Ingrese el año">
 <br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buscar"> 
 <a href="reporte.php" target="_blank">Ir al reporte</a>
 </p>
 </form>
 <table width="500" border="1" id="tab">
 <tr>
    <td width="60">Día</td>
    <td width="90">Mes</td>
    <td width="90">Año</td>
 </tr>

 <?php
 include('conex.php');
 ?>
<?php
include('busq.php');
?>

</table
```

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes intentar con **`num_rows`** para verificar si la consulta te devuelve algún registro.

```
?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 $dia=$_POST['dia'];
 $mes=$_POST['mes'];
 $año=$_POST['año'];

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   $query=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE dia like ? and mes 
   LIKE ? and anio like ?");
   $query->bind_param('sss', '%'.$dia.'%', '%'.$mes.'%', '%'.$año.'%');
   $resultado= $query->execute();

   if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
     while($muestra=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
       echo'<tr>';
       echo'<td>'.$muestra['dia'].'</td>';
       echo'<td>'.$muestra['mes'].'</td>';
       echo'<td>'.$muestra['anio'].'</td>'; 
       echo'</tr>';
     }
   } else{
       echo'<tr>';
       echo'<td colspan=3>No se ha encontrado ningun registro</td>'; 
       echo'</tr>';
   }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Ahora con cualquier búsqueda, se encuentre o no en la tabla, me hace el comentario de que no hay registros ! :( que podrá ser ?

Comment: actualicé mi respuesta para la parte del like. Utilizo *bind_param* para pasarle los parámetros con sus respectivos tipos de datos. fuente: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Quité los símbolos %% del select y los puse en el bind_param concatenando dichos símbolos a cada variable:
$query->bind_param('sss', '%'.$dia.'%', '%'.$mes.'%', '%'.$año.'%');

Comment: Ya encontré el por qué al hacer cualquier búsqueda, se encontrara o no en la tabla, me hacía el comentario de que no habían registros , lo que hice fue cambiar
     
     $con->real_query("SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE dia like 
     '%$dia%' and mes 
     LIKE '%$mes%' and anio like '%$año%'");
     $resultado= $con->use_result();

Por esto...

     $resultado = $con->query("SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE dia 
     like '%$dia%' and 
     mes LIKE '%$mes%' and anio like '%$año%'");

Con esto ya sirve al 100.. if($resultado->num_rows > 0){  y lo que sigue, mil gracias !

Answer (score 2):

No identifico que driver usas pero si es mysqli por ejemplo puedes tener una sintáxis parecida a la siguiente, que gracias al método mysqli_num_rows(), te entregará la cantidad de registros; queda claro que ahi solo deberías hacer una comparativa si es igual a 0 no tiene registros, en caso contrario existen registros

```
    if($resultado->mysqli_num_rows > 0)
{
    while($muestra=$resultado->fetch_assoc())
     {
         echo'<tr>';
         echo'<td>'.$muestra['dia'].'</td>';
         echo'<td>'.$muestra['mes'].'</td>';
         echo'<td>'.$muestra['anio'].'</td>'; 
         echo'</tr>';
     }
} else {
    echo "Nada de registros";
 }
```

Al ser mysqli si no me equivoco, tanto:

```
$resultado->mysqli_num_rows > 0;
```

o también

```
$resultado->num_rows > 0;
```

Comment: Ahora con cualquier búsqueda, se encuentre o no en la tabla, me hace el comentario de que no hay registros ! :( que podrá ser ?

Comment: si tienes registros mera duda?

Comment: Por supuesto, con el código que adjunté en la pregunta al buscar algún registro existente me lo imprime en una tabla, y al buscar algún registro que no existe me imprime la tabla sin información, lo que quiero es que al buscar algún registro no existente me de un aviso de que no existe registro alguno, le agregué a mi código lo que sugeriste y ahora al buscar tanto un registro existente como uno no existente me imprime el aviso de que no existe registro alguno, espero hacerme entender

Answer (score 2):

Leyendo la documentación de la clase `mysqli` de PHP, tal parece que no existe un contador de filas para la combinación `real_query()` + `use_result()`. En su lugar, la documentación sugiere usar el `affected_rows`, que para el caso de sentencias `SELECT` ejecutaría las mismas funciones que el clásico `num_rows`.

```
$con->real_query("SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE dia like '%$dia%' and mes 
 LIKE '%$mes%' and anio like '%$año%'");
 $resultado= $con->use_result();

if ($con->affected_rows > 0)  // aqui no estoy segura si se aplica sobre $con o $resultado, tendrías que probarlo.
{
 while($muestra=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
 echo'<tr>';
 echo'<td>'.$muestra['dia'].'</td>';
 echo'<td>'.$muestra['mes'].'</td>';
 echo'<td>'.$muestra['anio'].'</td>'; 
 echo'</tr>';
 }
}
else
{
 print"No hay coincidencias.";
}
```

Comment: Ahora con cualquier búsqueda, se encuentre o no en la tabla, me hace el comentario de que no hay coincidencias ! :(  que podrá ser ?

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta, y agregar al final el código que te arroja eso?

Comment: con el código que adjunté en la pregunta al buscar algún registro existente me lo imprime en una tabla, y al buscar algún registro que no existe me imprime la tabla sin información, lo que quiero es que al buscar algún registro no existente me de un aviso de que no existe registro alguno, le agregué a mi código lo que sugeriste y ahora al buscar tanto un registro existente como uno no existente me imprime el aviso de que no existe registro alguno, espero hacerme entender

Comment: Al usar la opción que te di yo, probaste con las dos opciones que mencioné en el comentario? me refiero a `$con->affected_rows` y  `$resultado->affected_rows` ? O sea, quiero saber si con ambas alternativas te falla lo que quieres?

Comment: Exacto, probé con las dos opciones, tanto con $con como con $resultado y con las dos pasa lo mismo, al buscar tanto un registro existente como uno no existente me imprime el aviso de que no hay coincidencias !

Comment: Entonces `affected_rows` parece no ser la respuesta... ¿Qué pasa si imprimes el contenido de `$con` y `$resultado` ? Puedes usar un `var_dump()` o `print_r()`.

Comment: var_dump($resultado); me imprime un NULL

Comment: var_dump($con); me imprime.. object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b396954eeb2d1d9ed7902b8bae237b287f21ad9e $" ["client_version"]=> int(50012) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0)  ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(21) Y más cosas, lo que sería creo yo la información de la conexión y de la base de datos.

Comment: Tuve que cambiar  $con->real_query("SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE dia like '%$dia%' and mes LIKE '%$mes%' and anio like '%$año%'"); $resultado= $con->use_result(); Por esto... $resultado = $con->query("SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE dia like '%$dia%' and mes LIKE '%$mes%' and anio like '%$año%'"); y trabajar con if($resultado->num_rows >0) para que me hiciera el comentario de que no hay registros existentes. Gracias por tomarte tu tiempo respondiendo a mi pregunta !

Comment: La verdad, es que el método `real_query()` y el `use_result()` parecen no ser los ideales para realizar un `SELECT`. Para ellos existe el clásico `query()`, con el cual sí puedes usar el ya mencionado `num_rows()`, que fue lo que descubriste al final en la respuesta de @mrojas.

Comment: Si crees que la respuesta de @mrojas te ayudó, recuerda marcarla como la aceptada ^_^

Comment: En si todas las respuestas que me dieron me sirvieron para tener una idea de lo que realmente debería haber hecho, lastimosamente solo se puede marcar una de ellas como la aceptada, de igual manera muchísimas gracias !!